# backward to previous page

Tags: asp.net

in my project I have two pages, page1 and page2. In page1 I have few dropdown controls  to filter the records from the db. And in the grid view I have the button as "View details". When I click the "view details button, the page has to redirect to page2 and complete details of that record will be viewed.

Now what I need is I have back button in page2. when I click that button, the page has to go back to page1 and page should display like how I left it, should not load as fresh page.... 
Since beginner to asp.net I couldn't find the solution for this issue.
Please provide with some example....

Very thanks in advance...

Comment: I have tried Response.redirect() method. But later I came to know through reference that this method create new reference to a form and loads the controls.

Comment: Then referred Server.transfer() method. But I don't know exactly how to use for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you `viewdetails` button click event:

```
 Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx")
```

And similarly in your page2 `back button` click event

```
Server.Transfer("Page1.aspx")
```

***The Server.Transfer method also has a second parameter—"preserveForm". If you set this to True, using a statement such as Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx", True), the existing query string and any form variables will still be available to the page you are transferring to.***

Comment: Hi I have worked on your idea. But it doesn't work. Could you please give me any other solution...

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to keep any such filters that you have set in session.

This allows you to keep the filters active even when the user navigates away from the page.

You can have a button the Page1 to clear the filters.

**Page1 Load:**

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["Filter1"]))
{
   dropDownList1.Text = Session["Filter1"];
}
```

**Page1 dropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged**

```
Session["Filter1"] = dropDownList1.Text;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have set.   Passing property in grid view, so how can I retain the paging of grid view

Comment: You can always retain the `PageIndex` too.

Comment: Okay fine. But in a case that we have lot of controls to retain its value. Then using session would be fine or any other way is there to do this better than using session .

Comment: @jeevacl session is ok. But remove the session when you have setting on your previous page. `Session.Remove(key)`

Comment: Most controls will rebuild themselves on Load. There are very few that will need you to maintain their state in session.